# Let L, K : V to V be linear maps between finite-dimensional vector spaces that satisfy LK = 0. Is it true that KL = 0?

Tags: linear-algebra

My assumption is that it is true KL = 0. My attempt at a proof:

Let v = {x$_{1}$, ..., x$_{n}$} be a basis of V. Then LK(v) = LK($\alpha_{1}$x$_{1}$ + ... + $\alpha_{n}$x$_{n}$) = L($\alpha_{1}$K(x$_{1}$) + ... + $\alpha_{n}$K(x$_{n}$)) = $\alpha_{1}$L(K(x$_{1}$)) + ... + $\alpha_{n}$L(K(x$_{n}$)) = 0 implies $\alpha_{1}$ = ... = $\alpha_{n}$ = 0 since the property of being a basis, and thus linearly independent, is preserved by linear maps.

Now, assuming this is even the correct way to approach the problem, here is where I'm really stuck. I basically just repeat the same argument but with the composition reversed, but I'm not sure I have a real reason why I can do that. Should I be using the fact that linear maps preserve the zero vector somehow? I'm pretty confused to be honest, if that wasn't clear, and I'm struggling in the class. I don't want the answer, but I would appreciate some help on finding the insight that I'm missing here. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not true. Think of 2-2 matrices that contain only 0's and 1's, and you can find an example.

As for your reasoning, many linear maps do not preserve linear independence. For instance, the zero map or projection maps.

Comment: I completely forgot that composition of linear maps is given as the matrix product for matrices. Thank you very much for your help, I've been stuck on the problem for a long time.

Comment: And thank you for reminding me that linear maps don't necessarily preserve linear independence. While fighting with this problem I somehow mixed up isomorphism and linear map. Thank you again for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Let $V$ be a vector space with basis $e_1$, $e_2$ and $K$, $L$ linear operators 
\begin{eqnarray}
K  :\\
  e_1&\mapsto &e_2\\
      e_2&\mapsto &e_2\\
L  :\\
  e_1&\mapsto &e_2\\
      e_2&\mapsto &0
\end{eqnarray}
Then 
\begin{eqnarray}
L \circ K  :\\
  e_1&\mapsto &e_2\mapsto 0\\
      e_2&\mapsto &e_2 \mapsto 0\\
K \circ L  :\\
  e_1&\mapsto &e_2\mapsto e_2\\
      e_2&\mapsto &0 \mapsto 0
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: very good example